How to get rid of this negative frequencies?
I'm a Quantum ESPRESSO user and I ran a ph.x-calculation with such input:
&Inputph
  outdir    = './'
  prefix    = 'rutile'
  fildyn    = 'rutile.dyn'
  nq1       = 3
  nq2       = 3
  nq3       = 3
  ldisp     = .true.
  verbosity = 'high'
  tr2_ph    = 1.0d-14
  nmix_ph   = 10
/

and the procedure has terminated correctly, I cannot attach the output file due to its size, but the phonons calculated in each selected point are positive.
Then I ran a q2r.x calculation with this input:
&INPUT
prefix = 'rutile'
fildyn = 'rutile.dyn'
flfrc  = 'rutile.fc'
zasr   = 'crystal'
/

and lately a matdyn.x with this input:
&INPUT
  asr = 'crystal'
  flfrc = 'rutile.fc'
  flfrq = 'rutile.freq'
  flvec = 'rutile.modes'
  q_in_band_form = .true.
/
7

   0.0000000000     0.0000000000     0.0000000000  60    !GAMMA
   0.5000000000     0.5000000000     0.0000000000  60    !M
   0.0000000000     0.5000000000     0.0000000000  60    !X
   0.0000000000     0.0000000000     0.0000000000  60    !GAMMA
   0.0000000000     0.0000000000     0.5000000000  60    !Z
   0.0000000000     0.5000000000     0.5000000000  60    !R
   0.5000000000     0.5000000000     0.5000000000  60    !A

from the latter, I obtain negative (immaginary) frequency in the output, and in general the bands are all messed up, while the frequency obtained in the first ph.x step are reasonable.
Is it an error? How do I get rid of it?
Thank you in advance!

Negative frequencies are usually due to your structure not being sufficiently relaxed. Try to use tighter convergence tolerance for your structure relaxation.

What is your etot_conv_thr, forc_conv_thr, and conv_thr in the relax or vc-relax?
Are the criteria tight enough? If you set tstress=.true., did you check if the stress is too much?

Phonons in rutile are unstable with GGA. Are you using LDA or GGA? See here https://doi.org/10.1016/S0009-2614(02)01401-X

hi! thank you all for the answer, the output of ph.x shows in every point I calculated positive frequencies, I obtain negative ones only running matdyn.x  to obtain dispersion lines,
I get negative one even in the points I have explicitly calculated frequency with ph.x
in other words, points with ph.x and matdyn.x aren't the same

by the way, I'm using LDA with tight criteria (etot_conv_thr aroun 10e-12, force 10e-10 and right now I don't remember conv_thr)

I have also tried calculating phonons in some points in between lines, but the result from ph.x shows that there the values are positive!

I haven’t used QE very much to say how to do it, but I suggest testing w/ and w/o including non-analytic corrections. Also check different methods for including NAC. I remember that having a big effect on rutile when doing calculations with Abinit a while back.
